# my login form always access denied

Tags: php, mysql

I created a simple login form. When I enter the correct `username` and `password`, it is always displaying the access denied message.

verify.php:

```
<?php 

session_start();

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn,'maindata') or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$uname=$_POST['username'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$password = md5($pass);

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from users where username='$uname' and password='$password'")
    or die("Could not execute the select query.");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if(is_array($row) && !empty($row))
    {
        $validuser = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['valid'] = $validuser;
    }
else
    {
        echo "<center></h1>Access Denied</h1></center>"."<br />";
        echo "<center></h6>Please wait while you are redirected in 3 seconds</h6></center>"."<br />";
        header('Refresh: 3; url=login.html');
    }


if(isset($_SESSION['valid']))
    {
        header("Location:index.html");
    }
```

login.html:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['valid'])){
    header("Location:index.html");
}
else
{
    header("location:login.html");
}
?>

<form method="post" action="verify.php" class="login" class="contact_form">
<p>
  <label for="login">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username"  placeholder = "Enter Username Here...">
 </p>

 <p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder = "*******">
 </p>

 <p class="login-submit">
  <button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>
 </p>

 <p class="forgot-password"><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
 </form>
```

Comment: var_dump($row) and check out if it is as expected

Comment: share your html code also ?

Comment: It's secretly telling you not to use `md5()` and instead use `password_hash()`...and probably hinting at not opening yourself up to sql injection.

Comment: problem in your html code plz check it else show full code

Comment: your code is vulnerable to **SQL-Injections** - imagine someone with the username `'; DROP TABLE users; --`. also: md5 has been insecure for **over a decade** now. also: the *root*-user should be **never** used for anything besides maintenance

Comment: Echo the query and try running it by hand, to see what it finds.

Comment: You have a redirect loop, `login.html` redirects to itself.

Comment: i already edited my code, can you please check and help me on my problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Restart your entire project from stretch and use password_hash() for hashing passwords and also password_verify for verying password, then do ur self a favour and read about mysqli or PDO prepared statements

Comment: Please do remember to mark answers as answers if they helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You'r code loops it self, Login.html checks if a user is logged in ( which they arrent because they cant login ) and redirects them from Login.html to Login.html meaning that you never enter your php code. You should not check if the user is already logged in when trying to access the login page.

Also you should consider making a file to check if the user is logged in, it could be something like this:

checkloggedin.php

```
<?php
     if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
     session_start();
     }
     if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == false)
     {
     die(header("Location: ./index.php"));
     }
?>
```

When you need to check if a user is logged in you can just start your pages off with:

```
<?php
include"checkloggedin.php"
?>
```